# Retrieving text from HTML5 to write to a file with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve info from a certain element in HTML and then write it to a file using PHP ?

For example:

```
<div id="info_needed">text needed</div>
<button id="submit info"> Click to write to PHP file</button>
```

How would I retrieve the "text needed" and write it to a file using php? (I understand I will have to use the `Write()` command, but I am completely lost on how to get the info.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Where is the file that you are talking about? Does it file on the server's system or web accessible file?

Comment: Make sure you are clear on the distinction between what runs on the server (PHP, which creates some HTML markup) and what runs on the client (JavaScript, and the display of the HTML). Remember that PHP has done its job, sent its result, and exited before the browser does anything. So the browser must **send** the data, PHP cannot **retrieve** it. Apologies if you already realised this, but it is a common confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to pull the text out. `$('#id').text()`

Use `jQuery.ajax()` to post to a PHP file that does the processing. i.e. capture the posted text.

You can use [`jQuery.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Make sure you set data parameter. `{value: sometext}` Your PHP script can then use `file_put_contents()` in append mode to append the text to the file.

P.S.: You could have a success function that indicates the action was successful.